# Stop at 40% when deploy robovm game in real iOS device

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 , real iPad OS 11.0.3, Robo VM 2.3.3 -SNAP-SHOT and Xcode 9.0.
After build and compilation phase completed without error. But When deploying has the error is 
[image]

It stoped at 40%. Does any one know this issue ? it took me a day :(

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem (same error, also at 40%) with Xcode 9.1, iOS 11.1 (iPhone 6) and mobidevelops robvm fork 2.3.3. I am using robovm with libgdx.

I was able to resolve this problem by changing the following lines in my gradle build:

```
robovm {
  archs = "thumbv7:arm64"
  ...
}
```

to the folowing:

```
robovm {
  arch = "arm64"
  ...
}
```

If i understand it correctly that means I have just dropped support for older iOS devices, so it's not a perfect solution. See this overview: [What iPhone devices will run on armv7s and arm64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422447/what-iphone-devices-will-run-on-armv7s-and-arm64)
Still, knowing this might help. In the long run, this is probably a bug or incompatibility in robovm that needs a fix from mobidevelop.